# How to connect ethers.js with MetaMAsk and other Wallets?

Tags: ether, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodejs, ethers.js

`const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)`

while using this i am getting window is not defined error..and i dont know how to use it. Do anyone has idea how to do it

Comment: It means the variable window is not defined. You probably should ask on stackoverflow, this is not related to ethereum but to your html/js code.

Comment: The `window` global exists on a browser page, if you are executing a web script outside a browser it will fail like that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used web3. It works fine for me. Try for ethers...

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // We are in the browser and metamask is running.
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // We are on the server OR the user is not running metamask
 const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
 "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/MY_API_KEY"
);
web3 = new Web3(provider);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to meta mask very easily using ethers.js

Try This code:-

```
const connectWallet = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const accountAddress = await signer.getAddress()
    console.log(accountAddress)
}
```